# Using var in an if statement

Tags: c#

Given:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar GetBar() => null;
}

public abstract class Bar
{
    public abstract void Baz();
}
```

This works:

```
var foo = new Foo();
var bar = foo.GetBar();
if (bar != null)
{
    bar.Baz();
}
```

and this works also:

```
var foo = new Foo();
if (foo.GetBar() is Bar bar)
{
    bar.Baz();
}
```

*But why doesn't using var in the if statement work?*

This compiles but can throw a null reference exception:

```
if (foo.GetBar() is var bar)
{
    bar.Baz(); // <-- bar can still be null?
}
```

Comment: Is this a question about the functional background of `var` and why this even compiles or don't you understand what `var` does in general? To say it simple: `var` is a shotcut for a definition, where the compiler will derive the type itself during compilation. `var` itself is a strong type, meaning it cannot change during runtime.

Comment: `var` is not a real type. It is used to tell the C# compiler it can just use the compile-time type of the expression being assign as the variable type for the variable being declared. So how should it be determined if `expr is var`? It makes no sense, does it?

Comment: @ChrᴉzsupportsMonica: No, it's not really about that - it's about using `var` in pattern matching.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `var` pattern *does* match null values, whereas a type pattern doesn't - that's all there is to it, really.

From the [reference docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#var-pattern) (emphasis mine):

> Beginning with C# 7.0, you use a `var` pattern to match any expression, **including null**, and assign its result to a new local variable
>
> A `var` pattern is useful when you need a temporary variable within a `Boolean` expression to hold the result of intermediate calculations. You can also use a `var` pattern when you need to perform additional checks in when case guards of a switch expression or statement

You can use a [trivial property pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#property-pattern) as an alternative though:

```cs
var foo = new Foo();
if (foo.GetBar() is {} bar)
{
    bar.Baz();
}
```

Here the `{}` is a property pattern which matches any non-null value, but `bar` is still typed as if via `var`.

Comment: Will the expression under `if` always evaluate to true?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Yes, I believe so - in this case, anyway. I'm going to check for another possible case...

Comment: It would be a nice "line-saver"

Comment: @Wouter: I think I've got an alternative - just checking now.

Comment: It seems crazy not to write `{ var bar = foo.GetBar();
    bar.Baz(); 
}`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: There are plenty of cases where it's useful for intermediate results. But I've provided an alternative now anyway which will help the OP.

Comment: @Wouter: See my edit - the trivial property pattern does what you want.